# Need help compiling Tor really bad

Tags: windows, help, development

I'm a newbie Tor programmer and I've just edited source code for first time, but I simply can't compile it in my Windows environment. Could someone help me or, if possible, compile it for me, since I've followed lots of guides(failing)?
Source Code: [tor-0.2.4.23](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ismv91hfixg3trw/tor-0.2.4.23.rar?dl=0)

P.s.: Forgive my horrible English.

**EDIT:** Ok, I compiled Tor and run it, everything seems doing well and it doesn't show errors. And now... why doesn't Tor Browser open? Did I do anything wrong or I just have to install it separately?
**EDIT(2)**For Example, can I download Tor Browser and make it run using my custom Tor?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's going wrong?
What have you tried? What errors do you get?

Comment: The tor browser bundle is composed of many software packages.
Tor itself can be run standalone, but the bundle is a different thing, based on firefox portable amongst other things. Compiling tor alone does not produce the browser bundle. 

For building the bundle there is scripts here:
https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbrowser.git/tree/HEAD:/build-scripts

Comment: So,what does Tor core actually do? Does it just create a connection? If so, can I use any browser or I have to compile other programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that that you are not compiling the browser, you are compiling the Tor proxy that the browser communicates with.  Therefor, you need to set a browser to communicate with the socks5 proxy that Tor builds.

Comment: Ok... how can I do that with, for example, Tor Browser? Do I need to modify torrc?

Comment: or with Firefox?

Comment: Nevermind. I compile it so you folks answered. I 'll ask it on another post.

Answer (score 0):

In order to compile for from source you will need a seperate compiler program. In windows there is one called Visual Basic . It's usually much easier and free to use Linux gcc compiler.  One option might be to install a Linux distro as a vm using virtual of and then installing gcc.

It compiles really fast in a Linux development environment. You mention you would like someone to compile it for you but then why not just use the precompiled binaries on the for project website? I doubt from your question compiling it yourself is really necessary. What modifications to the source code are you trying to make?

Comment: I modified it to use only 2 nodes (yes, I know it's not as safe as 3 nodes but I'll take the risk). About Visual Basic , do you know if the compiler is included in Visual Studio Suite? And how can I use it? Thanks.

Comment: Tor is not written in visual basic, visual basic is a language, and visual studio's compiler supports that too alongside a lot of other languages.

And typically you use Mingw Compiler for cross-platform c++ development.
There is a guide here:
https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/attachment/ticket/4520/tor-win32-mingw-creation-v1.txt

It's often more tricky to compile software like this on windows, in my own experience OpenSuse is great for cross-platform development like this, so I use that in a virtual machine.